# PC start only after a CMOS reset

Tags: boot, troubleshooting

Since yesterday my PC is not booting at all. I tried everything (swapped RAM, PSU, ...), but nothing worked. The only solution I found was resetting the mobo CMOS using the handy button at the back. And... it works! With a CMOS reset I can boot the computer, go to Windows, etc., but when I reboot the system doesn't boot unless I redo a CMOS reset, which is really annoying.

By doesn't boot, I mean the mobo light up (the CPU LED), the fans are spinning OK, and after 10-15 seconds, it reboots.

Specs:

- Mobo: MSI Z77A-G45
- CPU: i5 3570k
- PSU: Corsair CX600 (brand new)
- GPU: Gainward GTX 970
- RAM: 4✕4GB

Comment: Check your mobo's manual and re-apply all jumper settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like flashing a new version of the bios was the solution... It works now !